# Why FlatButton takes more space than it should?

Tags: flutter

The space around FlatButton is bigger than the space between Containers in the column with spaceEvenly alignment. This flatbutton contains nothing except a text widget. Does it use some default padding or something else which takes extra space?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(...),
        constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(...),
                Container(...),
                FlatButton(...),
              ],
            ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlatButton comes with some internal padding, which is like 8px of padding on each side, and for the text is 20px high.

```
   FlatButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero, // Will add default padding as zero
            child: ...,
          )
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Added the required description.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it has a default internal padding, use this to remove it

```
FlatButton(materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

> ```
> FlatButton(
>   padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
>   materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap
> )
> ```